# Make window behave like messagebox in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

So I have a function that if something happens I need to display a Window with a form and some fields.  And I dont want for the rest of the code to run until I close the window. Exactly like a messageBox, but with a form inside a some other things.  As far as I know messageBox is quite simple, that is why I am using window.
But window doesnt have callback method or something to make the rest of the code wait for the window to close (hide).
I probably have the wrong approach for this. I am open to suggestions.  I would prefer to keep using the window class with modal=true.

Comment: Not really familiar with GWT, but what's wrong with the [`DialogBox` class](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html)?

Comment: @Powerlord thanks, it is not working properly, maybe I am using it wrong. Anyways the look and fill of the dialog is different from what my boss wants. Maybe I could play with the css, but it might be easier to create a callback method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for your situation but this is how I was able to accomplish this. The caveat being that **I had full control over the server response from the form submission**.

First, you expose a method to your page that can be called from native javascript.

```
public native void exportFormSubmissionProcessComplete(MyPresenter cop)/*-{
        $wnd.formSubmissionProcessComplete = $entry(function(result) {
            cop.@com.client.package.MyPresenter::formSubmissionProcessComplete(Ljava/lang/String;)(result);
        });
    }-*/;
```

Then create the method that you just "exported" as JSNI

```
private void formSubmissionProcessComplete(String result){
  if(result != null){
    //Process the results from where ever you submitted your form
  }
}
```

Next, you craft the HTML response from your form submission to fire the exposed JSNI method. (I was using a java servlet so that's my example)

```
//...Arbitrary servelet processing code
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.getWriter().print("<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>FormProcessComplete</title>");
Map<String, String> data = parseData(buffer.toString());
  if(data.get(RESULT).equals("0")){
    //SUCCESS
    response.getWriter().print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.parent.formSubmissionProcessComplete(\"SUCCESS|" + data.toString().trim() + "\");</script>");
  }else{
    //FAIL
    response.getWriter().print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.parent.formSubmissionProcessComplete(\"FAIL|" + data.toString().trim() + "\");</script>");
  }
  response.getWriter().print("</head><body></body></html>");
//...Arbitrary servelet processing code
```

Last piece is to throw a FormPanel widget into a Frame widget and set the target of the FormPanel to be the server end-point that will generate the HTML response based on the example above. Then take your Frame widget and display it inside a DialogBox.

```
public static void submitForm(String actionURL, String qryString, DialogBox formProcessingDialog) {
        Frame processFormWindow = new Frame();
        processCCWindow.setSize("1px", "1px");
        formProcessingDialog.setGlassEnabled(true);
        formProcessingDialog.setText("Processing Form");
        VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
        FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
        //Do whatcha gotta do to make your form here
        panel.add(processFormWindow);
        panel.add(form);
        formProcessingDialog.setWidget(panel);
        formProcessingDialog.center();
        formProcessingDialog.show();
        processFormWindow.setUrl(actionURL + "?" + qryString);
    }
```

This won't be 100% plug-and-play but, hopefully, it will get you headed in a direction that will work for you.